# How to exchange crypto assests in italy without a bank account

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins

I don't have a bank account, I get paid at my job in my postal account which I can't use to buy or sell crypto.

I use bitcoin ATMs around Italy.

Some time ago I did something dumb, really dumb. I bought doge and no atm buys it...they only buy litecoin, bitcoin,bitcoin cash, ether, dash and some other minor stuff...

Is there any website that doesn't require a bank account were I can simply exchange my doge into bitcoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any website that doesn't require a bank account were I can simply exchange my doge into bitcoin?

Websites:

1. https://hodlhodl.com/ (P2P)
2. https://fixedfloat.com/
3. https://sideshift.ai/doge/btc

DEX: https://bisq.network/

https://bisq.markets/market/doge_btc